# QuantumLeap truncating float data from Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are using the Orion Context broker and now in combination with QuantumLeap and CrateDB. we are not so familiar QuantumLeap and need help with something that we find to be strange.

In the Context Broker we have entity with data:

```
{
     "id": "SC-5C0272FFFE8C206C",

     "type": "StreetlightControlCabinet",
     "activePowerR": {
         "type": "Number",
         "value": 0.7456,
         "metadata": {
             "timestamp": {
                 "type": "DateTime",
                 "value": "2021-12-01T16:33:13.00Z"
             }
         }
     },
     "activePowerS": {
         "type": "Number",
         "value": 0.5747,
         "metadata": {
             "timestamp": {
                 "type": "DateTime",
                 "value": "2021-12-01T16:33:13.00Z"
             }
         }
     },
     "activePowerT": {
         "type": "Number",
         "value": 0.4297,
         "metadata": {
             "timestamp": {
                 "type": "DateTime",
                 "value": "2021-12-01T16:33:13.00Z"
             }
         }
     },

.......

}
```

All three attributes has Number values and comes from "IoT agent MQTT/JSON".

Quantum Leap has subscription to Context Broker:

```
{
     "description": "QL - StreetlightControlCabinet",

     "subject": {
         "entities": [
             {
                 "idPattern": ".*",
                 "type": "StreetlightControlCabinet"
             }
         ],
         "condition": {
             "attrs": [
                 "activePowerR",
                 "activePowerS",
                 "activePowerT",

...

             ]
         }
     },
     "notification": {
         "http": {
             "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
         },
         "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified", "timestamp"],
         "attrs": [
                 "activePowerR",
                 "activePowerS",
                 "activePowerT",

.....

         ]
     }
}
```

The QuantumLeap (V0.5) creates CrateDB data series with floating point value type only if first value in the serie is fractional (like 0.7456).

If first value in serie can be converted to integer without loosing of precision (like 0, 1.0, 2.0, etc), the QuantumLeap will create the data series with integer base type in CrateDB.
As result, all following incoming data will truncated to integers in the database.

So this is strange since in the QuantumLeap sources we found that a "Number" attribute type should always be mapped to "float" datatype in CrateDB.

Anyone that may have an explanantion what the issue can be?

Answer (score 0):

QuantumLeap stores data in a relation data base. This comes with some limitations, i.e. if the first time you send a notification the notification has a given type, the following notifications, will be casted (if possible) to that type.
v0.5 is a very old version supporting crate 3 and not the newer crate version, I recommend to update to 0.8.2.

Following that, to solve the issue, you have two options:

1. Delete the table, and start data collection from scratch (of
   course this works out only if you don't need to keep data already
   sent).
2. Manually modify the metadata and the table in cratedb.

If that's does not help, contact us on https://github.com/orchestracities/ngsi-timeseries-api in case of need we also offer enterprise support.